# How to find the coordinate points of polygon?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my code I am trying to draw polygon I need to find coordinate points of polygon and display that coordinate points in to text boxes. Can anybody help me to figure it out?

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //points.Clear();
    // points.Push(e.Location);

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        points.Add(e.Location);

        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (points.Count > 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkBlue, points.ToArray());

        foreach (Point p in points)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red,
                                   new Rectangle(p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      points.Add(e.Location);

      pictureBox1.Invalidate();
       dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = points;
          UpdateTextbox();
    }
    }

       private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (points.Count > 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkBlue, points.ToArray());

       foreach (Point p in points)
      {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red,
        new Rectangle(p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4));
      }
      }


        void UpdateTextbox()
           {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        foreach (Point p in points)
        {
            textBox1.Text += (p) + "\n".ToString();
        }
    }
```